# Drive SDK: locating files in directories

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive SDK to implement cloud storage for my iOS app.  One thing I'm unclear on from the docs is how to query for files deep in the Drive directory structure.

I can make a query like:

title = 'TheFileTitle' and '1234567' in parents

But how to I find the fileID '1234567'?  I am creating a directory structure to store my data in the cloud but I only know the subdirectory's name.  How do I get the fileID that is needed for this query?

I could query for that directory and look for the fileID in the metadata but that just raises the question again.  That directory name may not be unique so I would have to know its parent's fileID to locate the correct one.

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive offers very little in the way of folder tree navigation. This is for the very good reason that folders are simply labels attached to files, rather than a strict hierarchy. So for example a file can have two or more parent folders. Although I've never tried it (I'm frightened it would create a black hole and universe would end) it's possible to create a loop where folder-A has child folder-B has child folder-C has child folder-A. Please don't try this at home, kids.

So the answer to your question, is start by querying for all folders and follow their parent arrays to build up an in-memory hierarchy. Then use that to navigate to a given file.

I would also suggest that you ask yourself the question whether deeply nested folders is a good idea. The answer may well  be 'yes', but you should at least consider alternatives. Remember, folders were an afterthought in Drive, so might not be all they seem.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will manage with what I have to work with.  I was just wondering if I had missed some important concept but it seems I have not.  Cheers.